# JAAS authentication with rest pages

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, single-sign-on, jaas

i am new to web services using java. i am working on an application that has login page coded using JAASLoginModule. from there it navigates to pages in the application which are rest-based. when i copy the URL of rest page in another browser, it doesn't ask for credentials.need to implement SSO between these two. could anybody provide pointers for the same as in what method and what all configurations need to be changed?

Comment: atleast add some code so anyone can understand what you did and what you want

Comment: can't get the code out for sure.login pager (uname/pwd)-->md-ui URI --> uses Spring Security --> JAAS (LoginModule --> land in application. now the jaas login page is connected to db and is being authenticated.i have to create a spring security in the md-rest page and make it authentuicated to md-ui.